# Searching in file content

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/directory'):
    for file in files:
        if line in file:
            if re.match(b'\x64', line):
                print file
```

How come when I search for a file which has the hexadecimal character `x64` (ASCII `d`) within its content, only the **filenames** which contain `d` are printed back, when I am searching within each line in the file's content?

Comment: You are not searching the file contents. If you were there'd have to be an `open(file)` somewhere in there. You are only matching against the file names which is exactly what you say you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` variable in `file in files` is actually the name of the file rather than the **handle** of the file.
For getting the handle of the file, you'll need to first `open()` it.

```
import os
import re


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/directory'):
    for filename in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, filename)) as file:
            for line in file:
                if re.match(b'\x64', line):
                    print filename
```

Comment: Probably works (if that char is at the beginning of the line) but does not close any of the file handles.

Comment: @tobias_k Corrected it!